# Call java methods with array parameters from Velocity

Tags: java, arrays, methods, liferay, velocity

I am writing a velocity template file (.vm) in which I get this class with reflection:

```
#set ($assetEntryQuery = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence.AssetEntryQuery").getConstructor().newInstance())
```

then I create an array and call this function:

```
#set ($arr = ['$category.getCategoryId()'])
$assetEntryQuery.setStart(0)
$assetEntryQuery.setEnd(6)
$assetEntryQuery.setAllCategoryIds($arr)
```

Unfortunately the setAllCategoryIds accepts an array long[], and not a Velocity array. What I get on the website is "$assetEntryQuery.setAllCategoryIds($arr)" being printed. Does any of you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the single quote around ['$category.getCategoryId()'] to have this: [$category.getCategoryId()]

EDIT
As a hack and workaround, this solved the issue:

```
$assetEntryQuery.setAllCategoryIds($category.getCategoryId())
```

Because velocity supports varargs in methods (see the comments in this answer).

Comment: Two things we should then check: does $category.getCategoryId() return a long? And does Velocity creates an array of long[] or array of Object[] with the brackets notation and/or does it tries to cast/convert those arrays to their required type. Btw, I have never tried liferay but I have a long XP in Velocity

Comment: According to the API $category.getCategoryId() returns a long. How can I check if Velocity creates an array of long[] or Object[]?

Comment: OK, so I went to see the code, and velocity actually creates an `ArrayList`. From there, I doubt the Velocity introspector will try to convert the `ArrayList` to a `long[]`. I feel this should be reported as a bug to Velocity because this should be allowed. I don't see any way out of this situation. Isn't there any alternate methods to use?

Comment: @PetarTahchiev I just thought of something, have you tried to invoke directly `$assetEntryQuery.setAllCategoryIds($category.getCategoryId())`. Velocity is supposed to handle varargs argument lists, maybe this is a workaround? But I have never tried this.

Comment: @PetarTahchiev Could you indicate what is available in your context? If you have `ArrayTool` in it, then it is easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks Guillayme, I tried $assetEntryQuery.setAllCategoryIds($category.getCategoryId()) and it worked, although it's really a hack, as it doesn't use arrays. Thanks again :)

Comment: @PetarTahchiev you'r welcome. I updated my answer to reflect that last solution.